# Parsing xml files using XML::Rules perl

Tags: xml, perl

I need to pars an [xml file](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/download?entry=ko00010&format=kgml) and I found this code on perl monks website, I can't understand the code and what I need is to have access to hashes an arrays element.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Rules;


my $parser = XML::Rules->new(
    stripspaces => 7,
    rules => {
        substrate => sub { 'substrate' => $_[1]->{id}},
        product => sub { '@products' => $_[1]->{id}},
        reaction => sub {
            my %reactions;
            foreach (split / /, $_[1]->{name}) {
                $reactions{$_} = { substrate => $_[1]->{substrate}, products => $_[1]->{products}};
            }
            return '%reactions' => \%reactions;
        },
        graphics => '',
        entry => sub {
            my @reactions = split ' ', (delete $_[1]->{reaction});
            $_[1]->{reactions} = \@reactions if @reactions;
            return '%entries' => {$_[1]->{id} => $_[1]}
        },
        pathway => 'pass'
    });


    print Dumper ($parser->parsefile('ko00010.xml'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You most likely do not want to convert large XML files into Perl data structures. This is very easy, but a very dumb way to handle data (XML does not map well to the data structures of modern dynamic languages and vice-versa):

```
use XML::Simple qw(XMLin);
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); 
print Dumper XMLin scalar(read_file 'kegg.xml'),
    KeyAttr => undef, ForceArray => 1, StrictMode => 1;
```

Instead, learn XPath and access the elements you actually need:

```
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'kegg.xml');
for ($xml->findnodes('//entry[@name="cpd:C00103"]')) {
    print $_->getAttribute('link');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. now I have proceed a little bit but stocked at internal nodes processing

Answer (score -1):

Right ... so you do not want to convert large XML file into Perl data structures so you use a library that builds its own data structure out of the whole file and then search through that mess using yet another language. How dumb is that?

If the file really is large (which the original poster did not say) you need to process the XML in parts. While it's possible to use SAX (if you happen to have learned SAX while being forced to program in, say, Java and the docs of XML::LibXML::SAX, XML::SAX, XML::SAX::Base, XML::Several::More::To::Study, ... make any sense to you), I'd suggest ignoring the "official" ways and use either XML::Twig or XML::Rules.

The first allows you to specify what tag(s) enclose the chunks you are interested in and gives you the XML in easy to swallow bits (with support for XPath should you be so inclined) and lets you throw those chunks away as soon as you are done with them.

The later allows you to specify what tags to ignore, what datastructure to build out of the others, what code to run once a specific tag including its contents is parsed etc. So that you can either build a specialized, trimmed down data structure out of the XML without ever having the whole document in memory, or build a specialized, trimmed down data structure out of parts of the XML and process those parts as soon as they are complete.

If you don't care about the memory footprint and want just a few bits out of the XML, then LibXML and XPath is the right way to go. If on the other hand you need most of the data, you may find XML::Rules much quicker. You set it up and it'll massage the XML into a structure that's easy to work with and may even compute or fetch data as it builds the data structure.

If the sixe of the XML is/becomes the problem, then instead of throwing everything you have out of the window and going all the way down to SAX events and the mess of side effects in the handlers, you SHOULD consider switching from XML::LibXML to XML::Twig and handle the chunks with fairly minimal changes to your code. Or, if you used XML::Rules to build the datastructure, change a rule or two so that it processes the data instead of passing them along.